# Twitter Bootstrap: How to see the state of a toggle button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I see the state of a toggle button?

With a checkbox I can listen to "changed" event of the checkbox and do a `$(this).is(":checked")` to see what state it has.

```
<a id="myId" class="btn" data-toggle="button"/>
```

But not sure how to do that with a toggle button?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can see what classes the button has..

```
$(this).hasClass('disabled') // for disabled states
$(this).hasClass('active') // for active states
$(this).is(':disabled') // for disabled buttons only
```

the `is(':disabled')` works for buttons, but not the link btns

Comment: sorry I tried it even as normal button, is(':disabled') doesnt work. Its always false

Comment: [here a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nP8C/1/) turns out we gotta wait for the button to change the class to disabled, the fiddle has an example of how to check it that should work

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery to intercept the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event like so...

```
$(this).click(callback)
```

you need to get creative because `.hasClass('active')` doesn't report the correct value. In the `callback` function put the following:

```
$(this).toggleClass('checked')
$(this).hasClass('checked')
```