# How to checked if Bootstrap toggle checked or not in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Toggle, but I don't know how to check when a user check it on or off  in order to send it using ajax.

how can I do that ?

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label data-label-id="<?= $data->id; ?>" id="message_status">
        <input id="check_toogle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
    </label>
    <div class="delete_message">
        &#10060;
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: Their documentation outlines how to handle events: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#events

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323671/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-see-the-state-of-a-toggle-button

Comment: Thank you  Robert C, I checked the documentation, but didn't notice this one

Answer (score 5):

I guess

```
$('#bsfdsf').is(':checked')
```

is a way to go. This should return `true` if checkbox is checked and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it didn't work, I used  $(function() {
        $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                alert('dfdfdf');
            }
        })
    }) as Robert C suggest thanks